# php/ajax to do list

Tags: php, ajax

Does anybody know of any small and simple ajax/php to do lists which I could incorporate into an application I am building?

Ideally we need to create to do and give them due dates.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Taskpaper+](http://code.google.com/p/taskpaperplus/)

Answer (score 1):

not an ready script but good tutorial:

[Working Demo](http://lastkarrde.com/q7todo/)

[Ajax / PHP Tutorial PART #1](http://query7.com/php-jquery-todo-list-part-1)

[Ajax / PHP Tutorial PART #2](http://query7.com/php-jquery-todo-list-part-2)